# How to replace NPAPI plugin to PPAPI plugin?

Tags: plugins, npapi, ppapi

I had developed a plugin using NPAPI so that it run a native exe file.
I heard that chrome will drop NPAPI soon.

---

My question here is

'Is it possible PPAPI plugin to run a native exe file on Windows somehow?'

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, this is explicitly not possible.